# Two Url's for one product

Tags: url, url-rewrite, magento2.2.6, product-urls

i have one product with two different url's

https://dutchmanaxles.com/products/axle-housing-rearend-hardware/rcv-934-cv-joint-lightened.html

and

https://dutchmanaxles.com/rcv-934-cv-joint-lightened.html

I'm trying to remove duplicate content from my site and this seems to be a problem that is appearing

Also, as an "SEO" standard, would the shorter url be more seo friendly

Answer (score 1):

Both URLs are correct but you should have a canonical tag in the head.

A canonical tag will indicate to a Search Engine what the page is which needs to be indexed and is also the page given in the sitemap.xml

This can be enabled through the configuration:

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Product

Comment: should it be set to No or yes

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mr.Lewis **correct** answer, double check your CMS pages. I had a similar problem with CMS pages being available under two URLs. Example:

> www.mydomain.com/myPage
>
> www.mydomain.com/myPage/

I am unsure why Magento does that but Google recognised both URL and penalised me for having duplicate content.

To solve this, I manually added a canonical tag to the CMS page under **Admin > CMS > Pages > [myPage] > Design > Page Layout** :

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href>https://www.mydomains.co.uk/MyPage</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: im not sure what cms is

Comment: would this apply to

Comment: https://dutchmanaxles.com/index.php because this started happening after the last update

Comment: If you go to **Admin > Content > Pages** there you can find you CMS pages. Check if you pages are available under two different URLs. Also, in regards to the `index.php` added at the end of your base URL, you need to enable server rewrites. Go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization** and enable server rewrites. Flush cache etc after.